# 'in' clause in mongoDB not working

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to fetch multiple users who have specific mongoids like the

`select * from users where id in(1,2,3)` (similiar to sql)

using mongodb php wrapper like this :

```
$criteria['_id'] = array('$in'=>array(new MongoId('4e0462f5506d3c0c19000003'),new MongoId('4e03608b506d3ca4130002c0'),new MongoId('4e03608b506d3ca4130002bf')));

return $this->mongo->db->users->find($criteria);
```

I'm getting a blank mongocursor object.

```
MongoCursor Object
(
)
```

Please help.I'm following example #3 from this page : http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And?

A cursor does not represent the result set. A cursor is an iterable to get hold of the result items - one after the other - like in every other database system.

Perhaps you want to read the cited documentation a bit further and check the examples on the same page.

Comment: Thanks. Got the solution here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php

Comment: Example #4 and #5 on the *same* page explain your issue.